# TXT file is not saving properly with Gtk# 2.0 , Xamarin studio

Tags: c#, xamarin, gtk#

I am a beginner in programming and it may seem a little funny to ask questions like this, but i have this code :

```
protected void OnSaveActionActivated (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileFilter filter = new FileFilter();
    filter.Name = "Text files";
    filter.AddPattern ("*.txt");
    FileChooserDialog fcd = new FileChooserDialog ("... ?", this, 
        FileChooserAction.Save, "Cancel", ResponseType.Cancel, "OK", ResponseType.Accept);

    if ((int)fcd.Run () == (int)ResponseType.Accept) {
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw= new System.IO.StreamWriter(fcd.Filename);
        sw.Write(textview1);
        fcd.Filter = filter;
        fcd.Destroy ();
    } else {
        fcd.Destroy ();
    }
    fcd.Destroy ();
```

---

Tho my Open file version works perfectly, I cant seem to make files to save properly into txt files, and i just dont understand anymore. 
Sos :(

Comment: Seems like you're better off doing `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fcd.FileName, "sometext");` instead of all that stream stuff.

Comment: or more likely that you have .Close() on the stream. THis is automatic if you use a using (  var sw = new StreamWriter( fcd.Filename ) )

Comment: does not seem to solve the problem, thank you for suggestions.

Comment: What is `textview1`? You cannot write a general object to the stream, but should be the string you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

If `textView1` is an actual control, then

```
sw.Write(textview1);
```

will not do what you want.  Instead, try

```
sw.Write(textview1.Text);
```

which will write out the actual contents of the control, not the control itself.

Also, as @HighCore mentioned, it is much simpler to do

```
File.WriteAllText(file_path, textView1.Text);
```